# set the width and height of the thumbnail in bxslider plugin in jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, bxslider

I used bxslider jquery plugin to create the slide.I want to set the width and height of the thumbnail. Is there any option to set the width and height of the thumbnail in bxslider jquery plugin.

Comment: thumbnail method is used as a custom pager.  its depend on you how to set thumbnail    width and height  using css or directly to thumbnail image tag ..  see here demo http://bxslider.com/examples/thumbnail-pager-1

Answer (score 1):

### For adjust width and height from jQuery

Javascript

---

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  slideWidth: 100,
  adaptiveHeight: true
});
```

HTML

---

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="imagePath" /></li>
  <li><img src="imagePath" /></li>
  <li><img src="imagePath" /></li>
</ul>
```

### For adjust width and height from css

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
width: 100px!important; // Set your width here
height: 100px!important;// Set your height here
}
```

Comment: An answer should never only link to the solution, if the site goes down, your answer becomes worthless. Please always provide some information yourself about how to solve the  problem.

Comment: No problem ;) You can provide the link, but always give information yourself as well, the link is more like a "source", not "go here and read yourself". :)